# Trying to create a Google Sheet search box on Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function getData(e) {
  var id = "1v_B85_8w_7Giry8DH-zM__v9c3BJYA-XPTcz9YwiktQ";
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getDataRange().getValues();
  var ar = [];
 data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(e.searchtext)){
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

I am getting the following error: Cannot read property "searchtext" from undefined.

Can anyone help with this? I'm very new and using a tutorial.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put e as argument of doGet. How are you calling getData(e)?  I see that you are using `~`. Do you know what it means?

Comment: You should include your HTML code as well, and how you are currently calling this function, and how your target user will call this function.